# Facebook notifications keep popping up

Tags: 13.04, notification, facebook, online-accounts

I have set up the Facebook account in the online accounts in Ubuntu 13.04. It's supposed to show me Facebook notifications on time; instead, it continues to show old notifications at a fixed time for several days. How can I fix this?